# How to open an entity manager after a close()

Tags: jpa, entitymanager

I'm working on a class that inject an entity manager in my dao classes
but I when I close the entity manager I can't open it again

This is the class

```
public class EMinjector {

public static EntityManagerFactory eMF;
public static EntityManager eM;

static {
    eMF = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit");
    eM = eMF.createEntityManager();
}

public static EntityManager getEM(){
    if (eM.getTransaction().isActive()==false)
        //here where I want to open eM
    return eM;
}

public static void closeEM() {
    eM.getTransaction().commit();
    eM.close();
}
}
```

I tried eM.getTransaction().begin(); but it throws this exeption :

```
Stacktraces

java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed 
org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.checkOpen(EntityManagerImpl.java:97)
org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.checkOpen(EntityManagerImpl.java:88)
org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.getSession(EntityManagerImpl.java:103)
org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.getSession(TransactionImpl.java:35)
org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:45)
com.iticsys.GBO.dao.EMinjector.getEM(EMinjector.java:21)

// line 21 is where I pointed before
```

Comment: Your code tells you how to create an EntityManager _eM = eMF.createEntityManager();_

Comment: I don't want to create an entity manager every time I want to do a transaction, instead I want just to create one and open it before a transaction and close it after that.

Comment: creating an EM is OPENING an EM!

Comment: Ooh, thanks man :)

Comment: Having a `static EntityManager` is recipe for trouble. Don't do that. They are not supposed to be simultaneously shared among multiple users/clients/threads/methods.

Answer (score 0):

In a JavaEE environment you should not use **RESOURCE_LOCAL**, but **JTA**. You can inject the EntityManager with `@PersistenceContext` and since EJBs are transactional already, you do not have to commit, close ect.

For a RESOURCE_LOCAL EntityManager like in your example above you cannot re-use a closed EntityManager, but must create a new one by using the factory.

Answer (score 0):

If you hold your current entity manager, you can call like that:

```
EntityManager em;

//for close
em.close();

//for reopen
if (!em.isOpen())
    em = em.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
```